# Can't stop the timer. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, timer

I made a simple timer, the problem is i can't stop it by clicking on 'stop' button. Also i found out that if click start button multiple times, the timer would speed up, is there any method to fix it? And how do i manually pass the desired amount of time(by putting it into the prompt)after stopping the timer or after the time has expired?

```js
let getId = x => document.getElementById(x);
let total = 20;

function check(x) {
  if(x<10){
   x= "0"+x;
   return x;
  } 
  
  else return x;
 }


let hours = Math.floor(total / 3600);
let minutes = Math.floor(total % 3600 / 60);
let seconds = Math.floor(total % 3600 % 60);
 
hours = check(hours);
minutes = check(minutes);
seconds = check(seconds);
 
getId('timer').innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' +seconds;

function start() {
  let hours = Math.floor(total / 3600);
  let minutes = Math.floor(total % 3600 / 60);
  let seconds = Math.floor(total % 3600 % 60);
 
  hours = check(hours);
  minutes = check(minutes);
  seconds = check(seconds);
 
  getId('timer').innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' +seconds;
 
  if(total == 0){ 
   getId('timer').innerHTML+= '<br>' + 'Time expired';
   return;
  }
  total--;
}

getId('set').addEventListener('click', function(){
 let total = +prompt('Insert desired countdown');
});

getId('start').addEventListener('click', function(){
 let timer = setInterval(start,1000);
 
 if(total == 0){ 
   clearInterval(timer);
  }
});

getId('stop').addEventListener('click', function(){
  clearInterval(timer);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
 <p id="timer"></p>
 <form action="">
  <input type="button" id="set" value="Set">
  <input type="button" id="start" value="Start">
  <input type="button" id="stop" value="Stop">
 </form>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should consider editing the question to include the code that's relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timer` variable is declarated inside anonymous function. So it is only available inside that function. 
You need to move `let timer` outside. Like below.

```
let timer;
getId('start').addEventListener('click', function(){
    timer = setInterval(start,1000);
    if(total == 0){ 
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
});

getId('stop').addEventListener('click', function(){
    clearInterval(timer);
});
```

here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jQKyVq?editors=0010) with timer set working, and preventing speeding up. Few things are missing (for example you should check if input value is a number), but it is working.

Comment: Thanks, that works fine, can you help with manual time set as well?

Comment: I saw your comment, but looks like you deleted it :) I've updated codepen once again to make code easier to understand.

Comment: Much thanks again, didn't see all the changes at first, so i couldn't understand the way it works, now its ok.

Answer (score 0):

Your timer variable is local to start method that's why stop is not working (make it global). Additionally in start method first check if timer is set and clear it if it is, to avoid speeding up.

Comment: Thanks, ill try it